# Connect to a WiFi-Direct Network with a device which doesn't have the WiFi-Direct feature

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Can an Android device which doesn't have the WiFi-Direct feature, connect to other WiFi-Direct networks as a peer connected to a Group Owner (GO)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
legacy Wi-Fi devices such as laptops can connect to softAP created due to WiFi direct.
if you only have one Wi-Fi direct device then you can create an autonomous group using Wi-Fi direct. This group will then act as softAp for your laptop and will be visible as 'Direct-xxxx'. Connect to this network using WiFi and passphrase from the device.

I am not sure that all of the above can be done by the WiFi interface given by Android, but I've created an application which is capable of doing the above, so yes the above is possible.